# Assembly Language - Division Overflow (4 digits)

Tags: assembly, stack, division, tasm

I'm having a problem with my Assembly Code. Whenever I debug this code Division Overflow was the always error. The code runs smoothly when the value of AX is only two digits.

What changes do I need to make the division work with 4 digit values? Thanks.

```
    ASSUME DS:DATA, CS:CODE

    DATA    SEGMENT

    X       DW          0

    Y       DW          ?   

    s       DB          "The aswer is", 0

    Z       DW          4

    DATA    ENDS    
    CODE    SEGMENT

    MAIN    PROC

    MOV DS:[Y],23
    MOV AX,[Y]
    ADD AX,4556
    MOV [X],AX
    PUSH[X]
    CALL WRITE
    POP[X]

    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H

    MAIN    ENDP

    WRITE   PROC

    PUSH BP
    MOV BP,SP

    MOV AX,0B800H
    MOV ES,AX
    MOV ES,AX
    MOV DI,5*160

    MOV AX,[BP+4]
    MOV BL,10
    DIV BL
    ADD AL,'0'
    STOSB

    XCHG AH,AL
    ADD AL,'0'
    STOSB
    MOV AL, 00001111B
    STOSB

    POP BP
    RET
    WRITE   ENDP

    CODE    ENDS
    END     MAIN
```

Comment: You can `add ax, '00'` (or `3030h`) to do al and ah at once.  Then you can `stosw` to store them both at once.  And you can `mov byte ptr [di], 00001111B` instead of putting a value in `AL` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `DIV r/m8` (e.g. `DIV BL`) the quotient will be stored in `AL`, so if the quotient is greater than 255 you will get a division overflow.

If you want to be able to handle quotients up to (but not including) 65536, use `DIV r/m16`:

```
XOR DX, DX  ; DIV r/m16 divides the 32-bit value DX:AX by the divisor, so we need to clear DX
MOV BX, 10
DIV BX
; The quotient is now in AX, and the remainder in DX
```

To be able to handle even larger quotients, use `DIV r/m32` or `DIV r/m64`. I'll leave it as an exercise for you to look them up in Intel's instruction set reference.